# asp.net control rendering and event wiring

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I am building a custom control, but the problem I am having is that the rendering is performed on `PreRender` where events are wired sooner in the life cycle so the event handler isn't able to handle the event when triggered.  I need to wire the event on `Init` where events can be processed during the page life cycle.

I've tried initializing rendering objects outside of the prerender stage and then adding the objects during that stage but it failed as the objects are created dynamically through a `foreach` loop so initializing objects aren't created properly.

My question is, therefore, is there a way to wire up an event during the `onInit` stage for controls that are rendered during the prerender stage?

Below is the source for the control:

```
public class DayView : Panel, INamingContainer
{
    private DateTime _sd;
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get { return _sd; }
        set { _sd = value; }
    }

    public string LogoPath { [UsedImplicitly] private get; set; }

    public string InnerDCls { [UsedImplicitly] private get; set; }

    public string FsCCls { [UsedImplicitly] private get; set; }

    public string LegCCls { [UsedImplicitly] private get; set; }

    public string FieldClasses { [UsedImplicitly] private get; set; }


    protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute("ID", ClientID);
        base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
    }

    public delegate void EPlannerEventHandler(object source, EventDataEventArgs args);

    public event EPlannerEventHandler FirstHalfAm;
    public event EPlannerEventHandler SecondHalfAm;
    public event EPlannerEventHandler FirstHalfPm;
    public event EPlannerEventHandler SecondHalfPm;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this);
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    private void DayPlanner()
    {
        var daysInWeek = new List<DateTime>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            daysInWeek.Add(StartDate.AddDays(i));
        }
        var containerTbl = new Table { CssClass = "ct_cls" };
        var containerRow = new TableRow();
        foreach (var day in daysInWeek)
        {
            var containerCell = new TableCell();
            containerCell.CssClass = "cc_cls";
            var weekTbl = new Table();
            weekTbl.Style.Add("width", "100%");
            weekTbl.CssClass = "tblDplan_cls";
            var weekdayRow = new TableRow();
            var weekdayCell = new TableCell();
            weekdayCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            weekdayCell.CssClass = "dayPlan_cls";
            try
            {
                weekdayCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(day.ToString("ddd, MMMM dd, yyyy")));
            }

            catch (HttpException)
            {
                Debug.Assert(weekdayCell.HasControls());
            }

            catch (ArgumentNullException argumentNullException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new ArgumentNullException(argumentNullException.Message));
            }
            weekdayRow.Cells.Add(weekdayCell);
            weekTbl.Rows.Add(weekdayRow);


            foreach (var hours in DateExtensions.HoursInDay())
            {
                var hourRow = new TableRow();
                var hourCell = new TableCell();
                hourCell.CssClass = "hour_cls";
                hourCell.RowSpan = 2;
                try
                {
                    hourCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(hours + "am"));
                }
                catch (HttpException httpException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(httpException.Message);
                }
                hourRow.Cells.Add(hourCell);

                var firstHalfAm = new TimeLink
                {
                    TlCssClass = "hour2_cls",
                    Identifier = day.Day,
                    WeekDate = day,
                    Date = day,
                    Time = hours + ":00" + "am"
                };
                firstHalfAm.DayLink += FirstHalfAm_DayLink;
                hourRow.Cells.Add(firstHalfAm);
                weekTbl.Rows.Add(hourRow);

                var hourhalfRow = new TableRow();
                var secondHalfAm = new TimeLink
                {
                    TlCssClass = "hour2_cls",
                    Identifier = day.Day,
                    WeekDate = day,
                    Date = day,
                    DisplayLabel = "30",
                    Time = hours + ":30" + "am"
                };
                secondHalfAm.DayLink += SecondHalfAm_DayLink;
                hourhalfRow.Cells.Add(secondHalfAm);
                weekTbl.Rows.Add(hourhalfRow);
            }
            foreach (var hourpm in DateExtensions.HoursInDay())
            {

                var hourRow = new TableRow();
                var hourCell = new TableCell();
                hourCell.RowSpan = 2;
                hourCell.CssClass = "hour_cls";
                try
                {
                    hourCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(hourpm + "pm"));
                }
                catch (HttpException httpException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(httpException.Message);
                }
                hourRow.Cells.Add(hourCell);

                var firstHalfPm = new TimeLink
                {
                    TlCssClass = "hour2_cls",
                    Identifier = day.Day,
                    WeekDate = day,
                    Date = day,
                    Time = hourpm + ":00" + "pm"
                };
                firstHalfPm.DayLink += FirstHalfPm_DayLink;
                hourRow.Cells.Add(firstHalfPm);
                weekTbl.Rows.Add(hourRow);

                var hourhalfRow = new TableRow();
                var secondHalfPm = new TimeLink
                {
                    TlCssClass = "hour2_cls",
                    Identifier = day.Day,
                    WeekDate = day,
                    Date = day,
                    DisplayLabel = "30",
                    Time = hourpm + ":30" + "pm"
                };
                secondHalfPm.DayLink += SecondHalfPm_DayLink;
                hourhalfRow.Cells.Add(secondHalfPm);
                weekTbl.Rows.Add(hourhalfRow);
            }
            try
            {
                containerCell.Controls.Add(weekTbl);
            }
            catch (HttpException httpException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(httpException.Message);
            }
            containerRow.Cells.Add(containerCell);
        }
        daysInWeek.Clear();
        containerTbl.Rows.Add(containerRow);
        try
        {
            Controls.Add(containerTbl);
        }
        catch (HttpException httpException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(httpException.Message);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        DayPlanner();
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

    private void SecondHalfPm_DayLink(object source, EventDataEventArgs args) => SecondHalfPm?.Invoke(source, args);

    private void FirstHalfPm_DayLink(object source, EventDataEventArgs args) => FirstHalfPm?.Invoke(source, args);

    private void SecondHalfAm_DayLink(object source, EventDataEventArgs args) => SecondHalfAm?.Invoke(source, args);

    private void FirstHalfAm_DayLink(object source, EventDataEventArgs args) => FirstHalfAm?.Invoke(source, args);

    protected override object SaveControlState()
    {
        return StartDate;
    }

    protected override void LoadControlState(object state)
    {
        if (state != null)
        {
            StartDate = (DateTime)state;
        }
    }

}
```

`DayPlanner()` is a method that is just a container for the rendering procedures.  It is easier to move around then the entire procedure;

Comment: Yes you can.  But without seeing some of the code, it's hard to advise you further on that...

Comment: Thank you for replying :)  I posted the source as an edit to the original question.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  The control is rendering properly but the event handler is not able to handle the event listener as the control isn't rendered when the listener is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building up a server-side table and other controls, you have to build this UI up earlier than PreRender; usually that happens in Init...  But MS built the [CompositeControl base class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3257x3ea.aspx) with this in mind.  That might be a better option.

Comment: Yeah you may be right.  The problem with the control as it is.  ControlState isn't processed until after the Init stage so on postback the selected date is not recognized and nothing gets rendered as a result.

Comment: On the other hand this control derives from the Panel class.  I should be able to access the same methods as CompositControl.  I don't know, I'll have to look at CompositeControl and comparing it to Deriving from another class.

Comment: At least from a comparison perspective, it might be helpful.

Comment: ha ha I'm so dumb.  I've been fiddling around with the page life cycle I've been so focused on making things work accordingly.  I didn't think to have child controls render at the same time as the containing control.  All I needed was to implement rendering in CreateChildControls() method.  It works perfectly now.